# K Means Clustering in Python - Using make_blobs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to figure out what n_features is in this make_blobs function. I am currently using make_blobs to make some artificial data for a k means clustering practise in Python.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
data = make_blobs(n_samples = 200, n_features = 2, centers = 4, cluster_std = 1.8, random_state=101)
```

The default value of it is 2 and it is described as the number of features. But can someone explain this example shown above to me? I think of it as 200 samples given with 2 features (an x and a y coordinate), and has 4 centers with a cluster standard deviation of 1.8.

What happens if we change n_features to say 23? Does this plot change? Does changing it make an impact, just because I am not exactly sure what it really do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only unpacking single value from function, like you are doing here:

```
data = make_blobs(n_samples = 200, n_features = 2, centers = 4, cluster_std = 1.8, random_state=101)
```

data will be array of shape [n_samples, n_features].So basically when you change it
to 23 you will get the array with shape [n_samples, 23].You can think of this
generated samples as coordinates in multidimensional plane.